# AS3 datagrid - Hide a row

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, datagrid, filter, flash-cs5

I'm using 2 comboboxes to filter a dataGrid that has been populated via csv file. The first combobox filters the columns and works fine:

```
//Listener and function for when the Agreement ID is selected
agreement_cb.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, agreement);
function agreement(event:Event):void 
{
    //get the number of columns 
    var columnCount:Number = myGrid.getColumnCount();

    for (var i:int=0; i<columnCount; i++)
    {
        myGrid.getColumnAt(i).visible = false;
    }
    var columnNumber:Number = agreement_cb.selectedItem.data;
    myGrid.getColumnAt(columnNumber).visible = true;
    myGrid.getColumnAt(0).visible = true;
    myGrid.columns[0].width = 200;
}
```

But I can't find anything on how to get the same type of function to hide all of the rows except the one they select from the second drop-down (codes_cb).

Any help is appreciated...

UPDATE:

```
loadedData = myLoader.data.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
    loadedData.pop();
    for (var i:int=0; i<loadedData.length; i++)
    {
        var rowArray:Array = loadedData[i].split(",");
        loadedData[i] = {"SelectAgreement":rowArray[0],"KSLTPROF0057":rowArray[1] .........};
    }
    loadedData.shift();
    myGrid.columns = ["SelectAgreement", "KSLTPROF0057", ......];

    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    import fl.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;

    myGrid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(loadedData);
```

Comment: What class are you using for your `dataProvider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataGrid` always shows all objects in its `dataProvider`, so to hide rows, you need to hide the data objects. Some classes that work as `dataProvider`s have this functionality built in that makes this really easy (Any Class that implements `IList` can be operate as a `dataProvider`), however `fl.data.DataProvider` is not one of those classes.

So I will provide answers using both, if you can, I highly recommend using [`mx.collections.ArrayCollection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) over [`fl.data.DataProvider`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/data/DataProvider.html).

---

### Section 1: [`fl.data.DataProvider`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/data/DataProvider.html)

For this I'm assuming that your `loadedData` array is a class property, not declared in a function.

```
function agreement(event:Event):void 
{
//your existing code here
    var dataProvider:DataProvider = MyGrid.dataProvider as DataProvider;//recover the dataprovider
    dataProvider.removeAll();//remove all rows
    for (var x:int = 0; x<loadedData.length; x++)
    {
        if (loadedData[x] == "SELECTION MATCH") //insert here your selection criteria
        {
           dataProvider.addItem(loadedData[x]); //add it back into the dataProvider
        }
    }
}
function resetFilter():void
{
    var dataProvider:DataProvider = MyGrid.dataProvider as DataProvider;//recover the dataprovider
    dataProvider.removeAll(); //prevent duplication
    dataProvider.addItems(loadedData);//reload all rows
}
```

---

### Section 2: [`mx.collections.ArrayCollection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html)

My reasoning for recommending this is because `ArrayCollection` already has the functions to do this without the risk of data being lost by objects losing scope, it also reduces the amount of code/operations you need to do. To do this we use [`ArrayCollection.filterFunction`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#filterFunction) & `ArrayCollection.refresh()` to filter the "visible array" without changing the source.

```
private var dataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(loadedData);
MyGrid.dataProvider = dataProvider;
function agreement(event:Event):void
{
    //your existing code here
    dataProvider.filterFunction = myFilterFunction;//use my filter
    dataProvider.refresh();//refresh the visible list using new filter/sort
}
function resetFilter():void
{
    dataProvider.filterFunction = null;//clear filter
    dataProvider.refresh();//refresh the visible list using new filter/sort
}
function myFilterFunction(item:Object):Boolean
{
    if (item == "SELECTION MATCH") return true;//insert your selection criteria here        
    else return false;
}
```

the filterFunction accepts a `function` and uses it to test each object in the `ArrayCollection`, the function has to return a Boolean, `true` for "Yes, display this object" and `false` for "Do not diplay".